# Min-height of ElasticText

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code snippet from a site for implementing elastic nature of a textarea. This is doing well except the fact that I can't set the height or min-height of the textarea to a desired pixel value. This is all arranged in the code itself which I tried to figure out,but in vain. I want to set the height of a textarea to suppose 10 px.Where should I make changes?

```
   //code has been altered
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
* ElasticTextbox that expands vertically or horizonally
* config:
* node: {HTMLDOMElement} : DOM Element to attach to :: Required
* vert: {Boolean} : Expand vertically :: Optional (default: true)
* horz: {Boolean} : Expand horizonally :: Optional (default: false)
* height: {Integer} : Beginning static height :: Optional
* maxHeight: {Integer} : Maximum height of node :: Optional
```

**minHeight: 200**

```
* maxWidth: {Integer} : Maximum width of node :: Optional
* minWidth: {Integer} : Minimum width of node :: Optional
* width: {Integer} : Beginning static width :: Optional
* resize: {Boolean} : CSS Resize :: Optional (default: false)
* overflow: {string} : CSS Overflow :: Optional (default: hidden)
* NOTE: most of these values should be set with CSS
```

However it does say you can set it with CSS - having never used the plug-in (and not reading the full code) I would suggest trying that first. (and do it anyway incase user has no javascript enabled!)

Comment: It is already in your code! Search through your code - look for the line * maxHeight and below it change that line to the one I have shown in bold (with the height you want)